# Energy-momentum tensor in the rest frame

Tags: reference-frames, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Given the energy momentum tensor of a mass in a general frame, how does one derive the energy momentum tensor in the rest frame?

Comment: Are you asking about the energy-momentum $4$-vector $p^{\mu}$? or the stress-energy tensor $T^{\mu \nu}$?

Comment: I meant $T_{\mu\nu}$

Comment: There is no guarantee that such a frame exists. Its existence depends on what you mean by "a mass."

Answer (score 1):

In the rest frame the momentum vanishes. The momentum density is $T^{i0}$ and the total momentum is the space integral of this. You need to find the Lorentz transformation that makes this quantity vanish.

Comment: OK. Thanks. So, if I understand correctly, one has to transform the energy-momentum tensor to a one which has zero elements except $T_{\mu}0$. If so, how does one Lorentz transform $T_{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: That is not what I wrote. You need the transformation for which $\int{dV T^{i0}} =0$.